# CapsNet Generative adversarial network

Tags: gan

I have a very interesting question. It's one month ago Geoffrey Hinton release his CapsNet paper. It's a complete new way for visual computing in the neural network stack. But my question is. Is it possible to use the CapsNet as a GAN.
I only understand the concept of the CapsNet but not technical limitations. So could this be possible?

This sounds for me for a nice field to research:)

Comment: I was wondering this too - in principle the capsules should help force consistency between sub-components of an image and avoid some of the weird monstrosities that CNN-based GANs can produce. However, I don't know whether it is even possible to build the generator component using capsules architecture. A CNN-based generator and CapsNet-based discriminator might be more feasible in the near future

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/CapsNet) you can find the papers, several articles and tutorials about CapsNet as well as current implementations in different programming languages and frameworks.

Comment: I am expecting this too. That should worth a sci paper.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible to use them in the *Encoder* (Discriminator) part of a **GAN**, since according to Hinton's original paper it's used for classification which means it fits in Discriminators as well even though the proper loss function is a subject to research.

I chose a topic of Capsule Nets in Discriminators of GANs for my Master thesis and I'm [working on the model right now](https://github.com/gusgad/capsule-GAN). However, I simplified the routing algorithm by not vectorizing the *DigitCaps* values (otherwise Keras code gets complicated, although I'm not sure if what I've done is 100% correct).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can use a CapsuleNet as the discriminator in a GAN.  See the following recent paper, which claims this improves over using CNNs as the discriminator:

[CapsuleGAN: Generative Adversarial Capsule Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.06167).
Ayush Jaiswal, Wael AbdAlmageed, Yue Wu, Premkumar Natarajan.
arXiv:1802.06167

The improvement appears to be modest on the tasks they tested.  It's not clear how to use a CapsuleNet as the generator, so the paper uses a CNN-based generator network.